# Combining fading text with reencoding video

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to renecode video then put fading text on the resulting video. Both of the parts work seperaetely but when I put them both together I get the error

```
Filtergraph 'scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1:1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2' 
was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

```
ffmpeg -i inputtest.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast -vf vscale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1:1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" \
    -filter_complex \
        "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c]; [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv0]; [ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
        [t1]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test1\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta1]; \
        [t2]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test2\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1[txta2]; \
        [t3]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test3\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=15:d=1:alpha=1[txta3]; \
        [mv0][txta1]overlay=x=\'100\':y=\'200\':shortest=1[mv1]; \
        [mv1][txta2]overlay=x=\'300\':y=\'200\':shortest=1[mv2]; \
        [mv2][txta3]overlay=x=\'500\':y=\'200\':shortest=1" \
    output.mp4
```

Any idea of what I can do to make this happen? If nothing else I can separate the two commands but I thought putting together would make the encoding more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaling of the video has to be carried out within the same filtergraph as the text overlays. I've added it below before any of the overlays. scale2ref has been adjusted to use the rescaled input.

```
ffmpeg -i inputtest.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast \
    -filter_complex \
        "[0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1:1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v];color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c]; [c][v]scale2ref[ct][mv0]; [ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
        [t1]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test1\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta1]; \
        [t2]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test2\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1[txta2]; \
        [t3]drawtext=fontfile= Helvetica 400.ttf:text=\'Test3\':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=15:d=1:alpha=1[txta3]; \
        [mv0][txta1]overlay=x=\'100\':y=\'200\':shortest=1[mv1]; \
        [mv1][txta2]overlay=x=\'300\':y=\'200\':shortest=1[mv2]; \
        [mv2][txta3]overlay=x=\'500\':y=\'200\':shortest=1" \
    output.mp4
```